# How to add parachain logo to polkadot.js.org/apps?

Tags: polkadot-js, apps, ui

How to add parachain logo to left side menu polkadot.js.org ?[image: leftside menu]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a pull request into Polkadot.js Apps like a prospective parachain did [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/7118). It will appear when the maintainer of that repository creates a new release (after your pull request is approved and merged).

Comment: The link to the change is missing from the post.

Comment: A PR like this one: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/6336